# How can i create a user profile in ext.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm working on creating a user profile view in my ext.js (and sencha touch) application. I have my routes set up and I have my data model in my data.js. I also created a form to show the data in. However, I'm having issues getting the user data to render on the front end.

index.js code:

```
// User Profile
var userProfileToolbar = {
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    id: 'userProfileToolbar',
    title: 'UserProfile',
    style: settings_sz2,
    ui: 'light',
    docked: 'top',
    items: gen_top_buttons
};
var userprofile_tabbar = {
    xtype: 'tabbar',
    id: 'userprofile_tabbar',
    style: dark_tabbar_sz,
    ui: 'light',
    docked: 'top',
    items: all_discover_buttons
};

var profileForm = {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'email',
            label: 'Email',
            labelWidth: '35%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'disp_name',
            label: 'Display Name',
            labelWidth: '35%',
            listeners: {
                check: {
                    fn: function() {
                        account.get('disp_name');
                        account.set("disp_name", disp_name);
                        account.setDirty();
                        store.sync();
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        {
            xtype: 'urlfield',
            name : 'url',
            label: 'Website',
            labelWidth: '35%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'location',
            label: 'Location',
            labelWidth: '35%'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name : 'defaultCollection',
            label: 'Default Collection',
            labelWidth: '35%',
            labelWrap:true,
            options: [
                {text: 'First Option', value: 'first'},
                {text: 'Second Option', value: 'second'},
                {text: 'Third Option', value: 'third'}
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'selectfield',
            name : 'relationshipStatus',
            label: 'Relationship Status',
            labelWidth: '35%',
            labelWrap:true,
            options: [
                {text: 'Single', value: 'single'},
                {text: 'In a Relationship', value: 'inARelationship'},
                {text: 'Married', value: 'married'}
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Gender',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'male_female_gender',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'male_female_gender',
                label: 'Male',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'male_female_gender',
                label: 'Female',
                value: 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Sexual Orientation',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'sexual_orientation',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'sexual_orientation',
                label: 'Straight',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'sexual_orientation',
                label: 'Gay',
                value: 1,
            },{
                name: 'sexual_orientation',
                label: 'Bi',
                value: 2,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Email Subscription',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'enable_disable_email_subscription',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'enable_disable_email_subscription',
                label: 'Enabled',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'enable_disable_email_subscription',
                label: 'Disabled',
                value: 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Default Access',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'enable_disable_default_access',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'enable_disable_default_access',
                label: 'Public',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'enable_disable_default_access',
                label: 'Private',
                value: 1,
            }, {
                name: 'enable_disable_default_access',
                label: 'Adult',
                value: 2,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Safe Browsing',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'enable_disable_safe_browsing',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'enable_disable_safe_browsing',
                label: 'On',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'enable_disable_safe_browsing',
                label: 'Off',
                value: 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Visibility',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'everyone_loggedin_visibility',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'everyone_loggedin_visibility',
                label: 'Everyone',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'everyone_loggedin_visibility',
                label: 'Logged In',
                value: 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            pack: 'center',
            title: 'Email Notification',
            style: settings_sz,
            hidden: false,
            margin: '0',
            id: 'new_share_emailnotification',
            defaults: {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                labelWidth: '35%'
            },
            items: [{
                name: 'new_share_emailnotification',
                label: 'New Connection',
                value: 0,
            }, {
                name: 'new_share_emailnotification',
                label: 'Video Sharing',
                value: 1,
            }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            ui: 'plain',
            style: 'background-color: green; width: 90%; color: white; margin-left: 5%; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-top: 15px',
            id: 'save',
            text: 'Save Changes'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            style: 'width: 90%; margin-left: 5%; margin-bottom: 15px;',
            id: 'cancel',
            text: 'Cancel',
        },
    ],
    listeners: {
        itemtap: {
            fn: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
                var user_id = record.get('user_id');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    Ext.getCmp('userprofile_recommendations_var').deselectAll();
                }, 500);
            }
        }
    }

};
Ext.define('myVidster.view.UserProfile', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    id: 'UserProfile',
    fields: [
        'email',
        {name: 'disp_name', type: 'string', value: 'account.get("disp_name")'},
    ],
    alias: 'widget.UserProfile',
    config: {
        scrollable: {
            direction: 'vertical',
            directionLock: true,
        },
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [userProfileToolbar, profileForm,]
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(users) {         
            var profileForm = Ext.getCmp('UserProfile'); 
            profileForm.loadRecord(this.data.first());
        }
    }
});
```

Data.js:

//User Profile Data

```
Ext.define('userprofile_model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'user_id',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'disp_name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'email',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'phone_number',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'pw',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'family_filter',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'v_orientation_chk',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'anc1',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'current_video',
            type: 'int'
        }, {
            name: 'current_video_type',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'video_history',
            type: 'auto'
        }, {
            name: 'video_history_chk',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'HTML5_only',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'filter_by',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'unlock',
            type: 'int'
        }],
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
            id: 'UserProfile'
        }
    }
});

var userprofile_obj = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
    model: 'userprofile_model',
    pageSize: 9,
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: "http://api.example.com/mobile_json2.php",
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'items',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        extraParams: {
            last_id: '0'
        },
    },
    autoLoad: false,
    listeners: {
        load: function(store) {
            var tmp = store.first();
            var tmp2 = store.getData();

            Ext.getCmp('userprofile_recommendations_var').setItemTpl(discover_recommendations_listTpl)

        }
    }
});
```

The issue comes when I try to pre populate the field with data.

For instance:

```
{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name : 'disp_name',
            label: 'Display Name',
            labelWidth: '35%',
            value: account.get('disp_name'),
            listeners: {
                check: {
                    fn: function() {
                        account.get('disp_name');
                        account.set("disp_name", disp_name);
                        account.setDirty();
                        store.sync();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Does not return the display name.

Comment: What, exactly, is the issue? Any errors in the console? Please be more specific so we can help.

Comment: Hi, sorry! When I attempt to pre-populate the form with data it does not seem to work. For instance, (I'll add this in a edit) value: account.get('disp_name'), doesn't populate the field with the user's display name.

Comment: No errors appear in the console